# Is that series-transformation known in the context of divergent summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, number-theory, reference-request, eulerian-numbers

**Background:**
In the context of divergent summation I'm analyzing the matrix of eulerian numbers for a regular matrix-summation method. Beginning indexes at zero (r for "row", c for "column") the entries of M are

$$m_{r,c}=\frac{eul(r,c)}{r!}  $$ and $ eul(r,c)=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{c}(-1)^k \binom{r+1}{k} (c+1-k)^r $. *(see for instance [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_numbers))*

The top-left segment of this (infinite, triangular) matrix is
$$ \small{ 
\begin{array} {rrrrr}
 1 & . & . & . & . & . \\
 1 & 0 & . & . & . & . \\
 1/2! & 1/2! & 0 & . & . & . \\
 1/3! & 4/3! & 1/3! & 0 & . & . \\
 1/4! & 11/4! & 11/4! & 1/4! & 0 & . \\
 1/5! & 26/5! & 66/5! & 26/5! & 1/5! & 0
 \end{array} } $$

The idea is, to sum a sequence $ \{a_k\}_{k=0..\infty} $ using the double sum
  $$ s = \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} a_r = \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} ( a_r \sum_{c=0}^r m_{r,c} ) 
= \sum_{c=0}^{\infty} ( \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} a_r m_{r,c} )= \sum_{c=0}^{\infty} b_c $$

I was studying that summation with various sequences $ {a_k}$ but I wanted to optimize the computation. For instance, if $ \{a_k\}_{k=0..\infty} = q^k $ and thus define a geometric series with quotient *q* the $ b_c $ are finite compositions of exponentialseries of $q $ and of powers of $q$:
$$b_c = e^{q(1+c)}+\sum_{k=1}^c (-1)^k \frac{z^k+kz^{k-1}}{k!}e^z $$
where for sum-term $ z=(c+1-k)q $ is simply a shortcut.

Writing the formula for the partial sums $$ ps(q,c)= \sum_{k=0}^c b_k $$ this boils down to the following series-transformation:

$$ ps(x,c) = e^{x(1+c)} \sum_{k=0}^c \frac{(c+1-k)^k}{k!}(-x e^{-x})^k $$
and we have in the limit $$ \lim_{c\to \infty} ps(x,c) = \frac{1}{1-x} $$

After arriving at the term $-x e^{-x} $ I've a vague impression I should have seen this transformation; but even if: I cannot remember. On the other hand - this summation-procedure is powerful, so this transformation is possibly interesting in more general use.

**Question:** Does someone know this transformation and/or can provide a source where I can read more about it?