# Proof for a summation-procedure using the matrix of Eulerian numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, transformation, divergent-series, eulerian-numbers

I've discussed a procedure for divergent summation using the matrix of Eulerian numbers occasionally in the last years (initially [here](http://go.helms-net.de/math/binomial_new/01_12_Eulermatrix.pdf), and [here in MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20759) and [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58083) but not in that generality and thus(?) without conclusive answers)); now I would like to formalize/make waterproof one heuristic.

Consider some (divergent) series $S = K + a + b + c + d + \dots $. To assign a finite sum to it I'm trying to use the matrix of the Eulerian numbers (let's call it Eulermatrix for now) to do something in the spirit of Abel- or possibly(?) Borel-summation:

I define the function $$f(x) = K + ax + bx^2 + cx^3 + dx^4 + \dots $$ with the goal to arrive at a valid/meaningful result for the case that $x \to 1$. The use of the Eulermatrix (see end of the post) implies then the introduction of a transform of $f(x)$ in the form $$ g(x) = K + ax + bx^2/2! + cx^3/3! + dx^4/4! + \dots  $$
If I now evaluate the sequence of partial sums according to the decomposition of the Eulerian numbers in combination with the reciprocal factorials I arrive at the form
$$ s_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k ((n-k)x) ^k {g^{(k)}((n-k)x) \over k!} \qquad n=1 \dots \infty \tag1$$
and if this converges to a finite value then I assume this as the (divergent) sum of the series and assume $$S = \lim _{n \to \infty} s_n(1)$$
I get meaningful results for series which have growth rates like geometric series with $q \lt 1$ and I think that the formalism of conversion into a double-sum and changing order of evaluation using the Eulermatrix gives also the range for $q$ as $- \infty \lt q \lt 1$ (because the $g(x)$ function is then entire). I can even evaluate the classical series $0! - 1! + 2! - 3! + \ldots - $ to which already L. Euler assigned the value of about $0.596...$ which is now called [Gompertz constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GompertzConstant.html).
So I'm confident, that my general reasoning using the Eulermatrix is valid.

But now: what I'm **asking here** is about the expression for $s_n(x)$ which reminds me of the Maclaurin-expression (which expresses a function by its derivatives at zero), but which I've not seen yet. Is that a valid transform? And up to which growth rate can this method handle series (I think, preferably alternating series)?

---

The Eulermatrix with a rowscaling by reciprocal factorials:
$$ \small \begin{bmatrix} 
 1 & . & . & . & . & . \\ 
 {1  \over 1!} & . & . & . & . & . \\ 
 {1  \over 2!} & {1  \over 2!} & . & . & . & . \\
 {1  \over 3!} & {4  \over 3!} & {1  \over 3!} & . & . & . \\
 {1  \over 4!} & {11  \over 4!} & {11  \over 4!} & {1  \over 4!} & . & . \\
 {1  \over 5!} & {26  \over 5!} & {66  \over 5!} & {26  \over 5!} & {1  \over 5!} & .\\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots 
 \end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: @wil:upps - that must have happened accidentally. Corrected (hopefully the best tag, I wanted something like matrix-transformations, Borel-transform (not the integral one) because I think this is related

Comment: np. I figured it was a typo. Except I just didn't know what you intended it to be.