# Euler type superdivergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, closed-form

Could you explain where this came from:
$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } (k!)^2 (-y)^k=\frac{G_{1,3}^{3,1}\left(\frac{1}{y}\mid{{0}\atop{0,0,0}}\right)+2 \left(\log \left(\frac{1}{y}\right)+\log (y)\right) K_0\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{-y}}\right)}{y}$$
where $G$ is Meijer $G$ and $K$ is the modified Bessel function. I tried numerical analysis
when $y =1/2$ with Maple and it seems to work.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(k!\right)^{2}y^{k}\left(-1\right)^{k}$ doesn't converge... How do you get this equality?

Comment: hello Marco a classical divergent Euler Series $$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } (-1)^k k!=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-t}}{t+1} \, dt$$

Comment: [A related question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311583)

Comment: @Guesswhoitis., you used to be JM? nice to see you back.

Comment: @abel, a good guess, and thanks. :)